# Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency: eclipse modeling tools

Tags: eclipse, ecore

I am trying to install ecore tools to use ecore diagram, but im getting the following error:

```
  Software being installed: Ecore Tools (Incubation) 0.10.0.v20100615-1639 (org.eclipse.emf.ecoretools.feature.group 0.10.0.v20100615-1639)
  Software currently installed: Ecore Diagram Editor 3.3.0.201706121316 (org.eclipse.emf.ecoretools.design.feature.group 3.3.0.201706121316)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Ecore Tools (Incubation) 0.10.0.v20100615-1639 (org.eclipse.emf.ecoretools 0.10.0.v20100615-1639)
    Ecore Tools 3.3.0.201706121316 (org.eclipse.emf.ecoretools 3.3.0.201706121316)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Ecore Diagram Editor 3.3.0.201706121316 (org.eclipse.emf.ecoretools.design.feature.group 3.3.0.201706121316)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.emf.ecoretools [3.3.0.201706121316,3.3.0.201706121316]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Ecore Tools (Incubation) 0.10.0.v20100615-1639 (org.eclipse.emf.ecoretools.feature.group 0.10.0.v20100615-1639)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.emf.ecoretools [0.10.0.v20100615-1639,0.10.0.v20100615-1639]
```

I understand that there is a dependency conflict between Ecore diagram editor and Ecore tools but i have no idea how to fix it

Comment: It is saying you actually have a much newer version of Ecore tools already installed. The one you are trying to install is much older - the installed version is 3.3.0 from 2017 you are trying to install 0.10.0 from 2010.

Comment: Thats the only version im getting no matter what repo i use

Comment: It is saying it is already installed, you don't need to install it again

Comment: then m supposed to find ecore tools via new -> other, but i dont

Comment: Please tell where exactly what exactly you expect and what you see instead in the current (not in your outdated) [Eclipse Modeling Tools](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-12/r/eclipse-modeling-tools).

Comment: i should be able to create a new ecore diagram..in my version i dont find the ecore tools to do so; when i try to add it via the update repo, the upper error appears